# Restart Apache in a version agnostic way

Tags: apache-httpd, wildcards, version, stability

I use latest Ubuntu 18.04 LAMP but might as well use Debian LAMP or CentOS or something else common.

To restart Apache2 I do:

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

But say "tomorrow" this changes the `apache2` changes to `apache3` or `apache-3` or just `apache`.

What will be the most correct way to prevent a fail in restart? I assume this shell-glob is good:

```
systemctl restart apache*
```

Will you use this way as well, or something else?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489256/how-to-automatically-install-and-release-upgrade-apache-as-well-as-restart-and-e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not just magically change.

When it comes to apache for Debian/Ubuntu/Mint or httpd for Fedora/RHEL/CentOS, updates keep the same name with only the version number changing so the service unit will be the same. If a new release comes out such as apache3, that will be a different package and you'll have to configure and set that one up if you want to run a web server with it. `apache2` will stay the same. `httpd` and `httpd24` for Fedora/RHEL/CentOS are different packages and installing the latter doesn't change anything with the former.

In regards to some of your comments, `apt-get upgrade` will upgrade the package to its latest version. It will install new packages for dependencies if necessary but it won't remove or change existing packages.